# How to only allow access to web server through SSH?

Tags: ssh, 16.04, lighttpd

My goal is to have a web server on my PC (running Ubuntu 16.04) that only I can access through SSH so that even people on the same network couldn't access the lighttpd server.

SSH has been set up but I have no idea what tool(s) I would have to use to restrict lighttpd access only through SSH (that means no LAN or other kind of access).

Comment: How would you be accessing your web server through SSH? Would you be opening a browser on the remote computer through your SSH connection with X11 tunneling or VNC, or do you want to use the regular browser on your local computer?

Comment: @NickWeinberg There are multiple ways I could do that. SOCKS proxy through SSH would be one way. But with that is that people on LAN could still visit the web server.

Comment: Just make sure your web server listens only on localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use the ubuntu firewall script and iptables to only allow yourself, and make sure your webserver only listens on localhost/127.0.0.1. *Note the below locked out all services except SSH to the IP address you specify. If you want to add additional services you can use UFW to add those ports or ranges.*

be careful not to lock yourself out. If you are already logged into ssh your connection shouldn't drop.

Assuming 24.1.1.1 is your IP, please double check.

```
apt-get install iptables ufw
sudo ufw status
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
ufw insert 1 allow from 24.1.1.1 to any port 22
ufw enable

vi /etc/YOURSERVER/server.conf
```

make sure bind is set to 127.0.0.1

You should be able to browse from this host, or use an SSH tunnel.

check this with

```
curl http://localhost
```

or

```
wget http://localhost
```

Good luck!